# Tableview header columns onClick freeze

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a tableview which I did in scene builder. When I select show in preview the window option looks good. When I click on the header columns out the arrows indicating the order (but if I maximize the window and I click on header) nothing happens. The table is not selected and the table stand still, as if a mouseTransparent could be.

This is the part of the table in my FXML:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="container" disable="false" focusTraversable="true" mouseTransparent="false" opacity="1.0" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="699.0" prefWidth="1203.0" styleClass="tab-header-background, tab-pane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="co.com.xdevelop.interfaz.FXMLDocumentController">


<children>
    <TabPane blendMode="SRC_OVER" disable="false" focusTraversable="true" mouseTransparent="false" opacity="1.0" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="699.0" prefWidth="1203.0" rotate="0.0" rotateGraphic="false" side="BOTTOM" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" tabMaxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" visible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <tabs>
        <Tab closable="false" disable="false" text="Consult">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content" focusTraversable="true" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="668.0" prefWidth="1199.0" snapToPixel="true">
              <children>
                <TableView fx:id="generalTable" prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="1120.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="236.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="41.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="42.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="80.0">
                  <columns>
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="36.0" text="#" fx:id="rowNumber" />
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="173.0" text="Names" fx:id="names" />
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Last name" fx:id="lastNames" />
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="49.0" text="Document Type" fx:id="typeDocument" />
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="126.0" text="Identification Number" fx:id="identificationNumber" />
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="251.0" text="found" fx:id="pensionFund" />
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="275.0" text="Time" fx:id="affiliationDates" />
                    <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="48.0" text="Changes" fx:id="numberChanges" />
                  </columns>
                </TableView>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: could you share the fxml? EDIT: i tried the same but for me it works. Build Information: Version: 1.1-b35, Changeset: 50e3d7cdf394, Date: 2013-08-27 10:45

Comment: maybe could be the AnchorPane.bottomAnchor?